# No puedo instalar Paquetes nuget de visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

estoy trantando de descargar paguetes desde el administrador de paquetes nuget pero no se me cargan, sólo se cargan algunos pero son muy pocos y despues me da un error

[Package source] No se puede cargar el índice de servicio para el origen https://packagesource.
Error al enviar la solicitud.
No se puede resolver el nombre remoto: 'packagesource'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisé las configuraciones de nuget y no veo problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor su ayuda con este tema ya que necesito poder agregar librerias necesarias tales como las de Entity y otras más pero no puedo debido a este problema.He intentado de todo incluso instalar via consola el administrador de paquetes nuget pero tampoco me deja.

Comment: Hola por favor su ayuda ya uqe aun no he podido resolver este problema

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo? Por lo que veo, tiene pinta de problemas de conexión, quizás algún antivirus o firewall que bloquea dicho dominio.

Comment: aaaaa no lo habia pensado, igual este equipo de mi trabajo asi que puede que los antivirus sean la causa. Lo revisare gracias

Comment: Hola mi firewall esta desactivado asi que no creo que sea por eso

Comment: En Settings del Packagemanager, revisa si tienes que añadir un nuevo package source como `http://packages.nuget.org/`